# Webpack4: Process CSS and SCSS file with separate entry point

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-4

How can I target all CSS and SCSS files in a folder with an entry point, process them and then output the result into a single file in Webpack 4?

For JavaScript seems very straightforward: In the following example, I'm getting all files with js extension located in assets/js then they are transpiled and saved into /dist/bundle.js:

```
const path = require("path")
const glob = require("glob")

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: glob.sync("./assets/js/*.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/js/"),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ["es2015"] }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

I'd like to do the same (along with the previous example) but with CSS and SCSS files. I've tried:

```
const path = require("path")
const glob = require("glob")
const mcep = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        javascript: glob.sync("./assets/js/*.js"),
        css: glob.sync("./assets/css/**/"),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/js/"),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ["es2015"] }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: mcep.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        /*options: {
                            name: "bundle.css",
                            outputPath: "dist/css/"
                        }*/
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new mcep({
            filename: "./dist/css/[name].css",
            chunks: ['css']
        })
    ]
}
```

but it does not work. Again, I'd like to target all files within a specific folder, process them and ouput them into /dist/css/something.css, I don't want to import them into a js file.

Thanks

Comment: Webpack is not like gulp for example, you have to have a dependency tree so webpack can work with it. You can read this article to learn more about it : https://medium.com/@matheus_gsilva/understanding-how-webpack-actually-works-b6fffd8c670d

Comment: Basically there is no way to do that with webpack.